# Neural Conditional Random Field - Forward Algorithm Recurrence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dynamic-programming, crf

I'm currently working on implementing a neural CRF as a project for school and am looking around for repos to reference.

I encountered [this](https://github.com/Louis-udm/NER-BERT-CRF/blob/master/NER_BERT_CRF.py) one the other day and have been completely stumped by the implementation of the forward algorithm.

```
    T = feats.shape[1]
    batch_size = feats.shape[0]

    # alpha_recursion,forward, alpha(zt)=p(zt,bar_x_1:t)
    log_alpha = torch.Tensor(batch_size, 1, self.num_labels).fill_(-10000.).to(self.device)
    # normal_alpha_0 : alpha[0]=Ot[0]*self.PIs
    # self.start_label has all of the score. it is log,0 is p=1
    log_alpha[:, 0, self.start_label_id] = 0

    # feats: sentances -> word embedding -> lstm -> MLP -> feats
    # feats is the probability of emission, feat.shape=(1,tag_size)
    for t in range(1, T):
        log_alpha = (log_sum_exp_batch(self.transitions + log_alpha, axis=-1) + feats[:, t]).unsqueeze(1)

    # log_prob of all barX
    log_prob_all_barX = log_sum_exp_batch(log_alpha)
    return log_prob_all_barX
```

From my understanding, the forward algorithm and its log alpha should be the log of the following where s_m is the scoring function - transition score from previous to current tag + emission score of neural hidden state/feature:

[image]

it seems to me that the code should be something more akin to `log_alpha = log_sum_exp(transition_score + feat_score + log_alpha)` if the log is applied.